# Как обратиться к функции, если у нас есть количество ее параметров (которое может меняться) функции и список параметров?

Tags: python, функции

К примеру, у нас есть *функция* и *переменная*, показывающая количество параметров этой функции

```
def f(a, b, c):
  return(a + b + c)
k = 3
```

Также нам дан список параметров

```
a = [3, 4, 5]
```

Мы не знаем количество параметров функции (k), также мы не знаем, что возвращает сама функция (то есть не можем просто сложить все значения списка a, т.к. функция может быть любая)

Как можно вызвать функцию `f(3, 4, 5)`?

P.S. Нам нельзя просто написать `f(a[0], a[1], a[2])`, т.к. не факт, что k (количество параметров) равно 3

Comment: Вы знакомы с передачей параметров в функцию с помощью `*args` и `**kwargs`?

Comment: и что это у вас за функция, которая непонятно что возвращает?

Comment: и зачем передавать количество аргументов, когда есть список? Может смысл в том, что бы список подогнать под количество? То есть либо срезать, либо дополнить... И тогда уже вызывать функцию с параметрами из "правильного" списка. ) А то переменная с количеством параметров есть, но почему то количество параметров не известно...

Answer (score 1):

Как указали в комментариях, можно использовать *args или kwargs

```
def f(a, b, c):
  return(a + b + c)

var_list = [3, 4, 5]
var_dict = {
    'a': 3,
    'b': 4,
    'c': 5,
}
```

в итоге Вы можете вызывать Вашу метод таким образом

```
  call_from_list = f(*var_list)
  call_from_dict = f(**var_dict)
```

Comment: Если быть точным, то в вашем примере количество параметров функции тоже фиксированное. Чтобы количество могло быть произвольным *args и **qwargs используется при объявлении функции. То есть:  `def f(*args,**qwargs): return {k:v+sum(args) for k,v in qwargs.items()}`  . Тогда при вызове появляется возможность задать любое количество параметров, типа  `f(10,20,30,a=100,b=200)`  , что вернет  `{'a': 160, 'b': 260}`

Comment: Да, я согласен. Но я не уверен, что стоит сразу сильно усложнять на тестовом примере. Если его заинтересует эта тема, то он сможет найти информацию о том как что такое *args и **kwargs и уже в деталях ее изучить